# Mobile back button access through flutter

Tags: flutter

On using onWillPop the flutter app bottomScreen closes for two conditions.

1. On tapping outside bottom sheet.
2. On pressing mobile back button.

How to make first condition disable i.e. bottom sheet should only close on clicking mobile back button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `isDismissible` property of showModalBottomSheet. It works only for outside tap.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
            isDismissible: false,
    ////other
    
    )
```

Comment: Is there any solution that if I want to pop context twice for back button click but only once for on tapping outside bottom sheet? i.e., separate action for separate event